# Java Listening to a UDP port

Tags: java, networking

I want to listen to a UDP port to receive the information it is transferring in wireshark it looks like this [image: Wireshark Filtered Image]

all that I found was people creating ServerSockets but when i try that I dont get any output from the console.

```
package me.xenopyax.albionmarket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(5056);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        while(true)
            {
          DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
          serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
          String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
          System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
          InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
          int port = receivePacket.getPort();
          String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
          sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
          DatagramPacket sendPacket =
          new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
          serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
       }

    }

}
```

Am I corret with using ServersSockets to listen to the port. or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? `ServerSocket` is for TCP.

Comment: Why is it that I always see ServerSockets used when I search for "listening on UDP port java" ?

Comment: That's not when I get when I search (Google) for "listening on UDP port java".

Comment: updated code, but still doesnt work...

Comment: @XenoPyax If that' really what you find, it is befause you're using the wrong terminology. `ServerSockets` listen. UDP sockets *receive.*

Comment: @XenoPyax - This code seems to receive a UDP message on port 5056, print it, and echo it back to the sender.  How are you sending messages to this program?  Please show us the code or commands you are using ... so that we have a proper "minimal **reproducible** example" of your problem.

Comment: Its a game that is sending market data to the port 5056 and I want to receive that data and then translate it

Answer (score 2):

As the comments state, `ServerSocket` is for stream-based protocol and UDP is not a stream-based protocol.  You need to use `DatagramSocket` to read UDP packets.

However `DatagramSocket` can only be used to read UDP packets that are addressed to the current machine ... one way or another.

And that doesn't match what Wireshark does.  In reality, Wireshark

- receives raw network packets (at the ISO layer 2) aka IP packets, and
- often puts the NIC into "promiscuous" mode so that it can pick up packets that are not addressed to the host.

You can't do either of those things using the Java SE libraries, but there some third-party alternatives; e.g.

- [How do I read and write raw ip packets from java on a mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039/how-do-i-read-and-write-raw-ip-packets-from-java-on-a-mac)
- [Can I do low level network programming in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755297/can-i-do-low-level-network-programming-in-java)

Comment: I somehow achieved it some time ago reading the hexcodes from the packets on the UDP port

Comment: I doubt it.  But if you say you did it before, I suggest that you do it again, the same way that you did it the first time :-).   If you want help with your code, include it in the question itself ... as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: If you want help with the code, put it in the question.  Not a link to an image or a pastebin link.